# Prove that given graph consisting of vertices numbered with composite numbers is not eulerian

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

We have the following graph definition:

$$V(G_n)=\{1\leq m\leq n : m = pq\}$$ (so vetices of $G_n$ are composite numbers)
$$E(G_n)=\{\{i,j\}:i\perp j\}$$ (so vertices $i,j$ are connected if and only if they are realtively primes)

The problem asks us to prove that $G_{1000}$ is not eulerian. So it seems easy - we only need to find two vertices, such that the parity of degree of first is different than that of the second (or - even simpler - find a vertex with odd degree). Unfortunately I've been struggling with finding such pair for quite some time now. Where should I look then?

Comment: Doesn't the vertex $2$ have odd degree, since it shares its one divisor with the $499$ other even numbers between $4$ and $1000$, inclusive?

Comment: $2$ is prime, so it's not a vertex of the graph

Comment: Brian, I think not because the neighbours are the 502 with which it is not relatively prime.

Comment: @BrianTung You get an edge for relatively prime numbers, plus primes are not included in the vertices. You could use 4 as the vertex, but still it would be however many odd numbers are not prime that would give the degree.

Comment: Oh, there is also what qiubit said.

Comment: Is $1$ composite?

Comment: Let's also say for clarification that $1$ is not a vertex of the graph too, it's nor prime nor composite.

Comment: Yup, sorry, I totally missed that.

Comment: I find 427 vertices with odd degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the prime $223$ , consider the neighbors of $2\cdot 223$, they are all the odd composite numbers except for $3\cdot 223$.

Consider the neighbors of $4$. They are all the odd composite numbers. These two sets differ by one element, hence vertices $4$ and $2\cdot 223$ have orders of distinct parity. This implies there is a vertex of odd order, so the graph is not Eulerian.